# php removing part of string

Tags: php

Why does this not remove the http:// of the string?

```
$rurl = 'http://www.google.com';
$httpposi = strpos($rurl,'://');
echo $httpposi;
if($httpposi === true) {
$url=substr($rurl, strpos($rurl, '://') + 3);
echo $url;
} else {
$url=$rurl;
echo '3'.$url.'2';
}

echo $url;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if($httpposi === true) {
```

you need:

```
if($httpposi !== false) {
```

since if it *is* found in the string, it will return an offset as an integer, and you are doing a strict comparison and strictly an non-zero, positive integer is not equal to the boolean value `true`.

```
8 == true // true
8 === true // false, because 8 is not a boolean
0 == true // false, but we need to know if the needle is at position 0
```

so:

```
0 !== false // true, string was found
8 !== false // true, string was found
false !== false // false, string was not found
```

If the sequence is found at the beginning of the string, the falsy `0` will be returned, thus the need to strictly compare to `false` to know that it has not been found at all.

http://ideone.com/QXBs7

Comment: Hi Karim, if the thing I was looking for was at position 0, would your method  still work?

Comment: @David19801 - yes, I've updated the explanation a bit. Will try to clarify some more.

Answer (score 1):

As a few others already posted: Do not compare `$httpposi` with a boolean value! The return value of the `strpos` function is an integer value if it has found an occurence, but can return either `false`, `0` or `""` if it didn't find your passed string.

For more information, take a look at the [PHP.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use preg_replace instead and get rid of the problem another way:

```
$url=preg_replace('~^https?://~i','','http://www.google.com')
```

Caters for https as well. Just remove [s]? if that's not what you want.
The /i is for ignoring case.

Comment: Thanks, forward slashes was a bad choice of course.. :-)
Brackets around the s I would have kept myself for readability..

Answer (score 0):

```
if($httpposi !== false) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `if($httpposi === true) {` to `if($httpposi) {` or `if($httpposi == true) {`, since `$httpposi = 4` isn't `===` to `true`.